# try to get here maps image but get 414 Request-URI Too Large

Tags: reactjs, here-api

I'm using the route link https://image.maps.ls.hereapi.com/mia/1.6/route this one, and from what i read from the documentation from here "https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-image/dev_guide/topics/resource-route.html" they support POST method with payload 8k maximum for bigger data, so i have been trying to get the Here map image using POST Method using axios and XMLHttpRequest but i always get error 401 unauthorized, even when i already set the apikey on the header, anyone know how to achive this?

this is what i have been trying with XMLHttpRequest:

```
const params = `apiKey=${getHereApiKey()}&w=${width}&h=${height}&lc0=${baseColor}&sc0=${baseColor}&lw0=5`;

 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", `https://image.maps.ls.hereapi.com/mia/1.6/route`, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "Application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization","apiKey " + getHereApiKey());
    xhr.send(params);

    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (xhr.status != 200) {
        console.error(`Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`);
      } else {
        console.log("xhr", xhr)
        setUrl(xhr.responseURL)
      }
    };
```

this one with axios :

```
var body = {
      "apiKey": API_KEY,
      "routes": [
        {
          "waypoints": [
            {
              "lat": 37.99392,
              "lng": -122.99964
            },
            {
              "lat": 37.97011,
              "lng": -122.96910
            }
          ],
          "color": baseColor
        },
        {
          "waypoints": [
            {
              "lat": 37.77011,
              "lng": -122.46910
            },
            {
              "lat": 37.76122,
              "lng": -122.41488
            }
          ],
          "color": baseColor
        }
      ],
      "w": width,
      "h": height,
      "imageSize": {
        "width": width,
        "height": height
      }
    }
```

```
const config = {
      headers: {
        apikey: API_KEY,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    };

    axios.post('https://image.maps.ls.hereapi.com/mia/1.6/route', body, config)
      .then(response => {
        console.log("response", response)
        // handle response
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("error", error)
        // handle error
      });
```

both of it can't recognized the apikey that i have put on the header, but when i tried to put the apikey on the query param it works, so there's nothing wrong with the key. anyone know how to do it properly with POST request and the correct Payload? Thank You

Answer (score 1):

After testing your code, I notice there is a CORS issue with this API.
If you debug this using the network tab in your browser you should also see it.

```
blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Since this API is already old and in maintenance mode, I would simply try moving to another API or set of APIs to accomplish your goal.

One last thing, you should not use http://locahost, and use your server's IP instead, otherwise you may still another type of CORS error when using the other APIs that do have a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header.

Comment: i see, in that case theres's nothing we can do, Thank you so much for responding and checking it for me!